# What does nocf-www mean?

Tags: url, web, protocols, network-protocols

For example I did a google search for Kibana and the first result was `nocf-www.elastic.co/products/kibana` I've never seen this before, and a couple of google searches haven't been fruitful. What is this?

Comment: Looks like a subdomain to me. Does it have to mean something in particular?

Answer (score 1):

I work for Elastic and what I can tell is that "nocf" stands for "No CloudFront".

These links where not supposed to be public, but they leaked due to a glitch. We are removing all of them.